# How to create and sign a monero transaction by hand

Tags: transaction-data, monerod-commands

As the title states... what I mean is what does the json/rpc command look like and can someone give an example and explain it? I would like to use RPC to get blockchain information, then manually construct a transaction and sign it from that returned information. I understand this would involve a lot of work

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify ? You want to use RPC to get blockchain info, then manually construct a tx and sign it from that returned info ? That'd be a LOT of manual work.

Comment: Yes. For example, the information that someone might need to develop a new wallet using RPC.

Comment: @JeffreyLebowski I edited the question based on the comments to help clarify your intent. Not everyone reads question comments.

Answer (score 1):

The wallet RPC has a method [transfer](https://www.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#transfer) which you can call with parameters `do_not_relay:true` and `get_tx_metadata:true` which will allow you to create a transaction but not relay to the network immediately. When you are ready to send, you can call the method [relay_tx](https://www.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#relay_tx).